# Difference between font-family and face inside style attribute

Tags: html, fonts, styles

I am a newbie learning html and in the style attribute chapter I can't seem to understand the difference between font-family and face inside style attribute

When to use font-family and when to use face?

Comment: Please read [mdn webdocs: @font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face). `@font-face` is required for mapping a font-family name to a specific font file. If a `font-family` defined by `@font-face` isn't used in any css rule and applied anywhere in your HTML - the font file won't be loaded.

Comment: @herrstrietzel I have not started learning css sir. I referred in the title that I have been using font-face and font-family inside style tag in HTML like:                  <p style="font-family:verdana;"></p>           Forgive me for any mistake as I am a newbie.